# Jquery how to use on() with array

Tags: jquery, events, listener

```
$(document).on('change','#id1,#id2,#id3', function(){
       //run my code
    });
```

The above works

below does not

```
  var ids = ["#id1","#id2","#id3"];

  $(document).on('change', ids , function(){
           //run my code
        });
```

I also tried to `ids.tostring()` to see if changing array to string would work.

Answer (score 1):

[Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array into a string:

```
var ids = ["#id1","#id2","#id3"];

$(document).on('change', ids.join(','), function(){
    //run my code
});
```